# Folium Marker-Cluster map is not visualized for a large dataset

Tags: python, visualization, folium, markerclusterer

Im trying to create a Marker-Cluster map using folium for some data, I first tried with a sample dataset where the sample size is 1000 row points, which ran fine with no error. But when im trying to implement the same on the actual dataset which is of size 180000 row points, It is failing to create a map.
Im using Googlecolab for this project. The code is running fine without any error but within a minute there isa small popup saying "Runtime Disconnected".
Following is the code used:

```
map2 = folium.Map(location=[30, -90], zoom_start=4)

marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(map2)

globterr.apply(lambda row: folium.Marker(location=[row['latitude'], row['longitude']]).add_to(marker_cluster), axis=1)

map2
```

Is there a limit in googlecolab for large datasets, or can i add parameter to increase the runtime for the above code. kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Fast Marker Cluster has worked for this case. Following is the code:

```
map3 = folium.Map(location=[15, 20], zoom_start=3)
map3.add_child(FastMarkerCluster(df2[['latitude', 'longitude']].values.tolist()))
map3.save("save_file.html")

map3
```